# How to replicate a user plugin made table value, to this user's custom meta table value?

Tags: database, user-meta

I have a plugin that gets a value on user register and stores it in its own automatic made table.

I need to set that same value into a usermeta custom meta_value, so the user will be able to see it from user settings. (this will also make that I will be able to see it in the users admin panel etc..)

**See final screenshot** (self explanatory for all the post) I was going to paste another here but I prefer this post to be lighter.

I already have the code to set a usermeta custom value and let the user modify it from settings panel (already working). (user won't be able to modify it, this will be blocked, just here for testing purposes)

**I share the code and a screenshot below, notice the usermeta custom value is empty now..**
(I simply added this as a plugin in wordpress)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: #Addy Plugin
Plugin URI: #
Description: #
Version: 0.1
Author: #
Author URI: #
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: #
*/
//$wpdb->show_errors(); $wpdb->print_error();
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields_uny' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields_uny' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields_uny( $user_id ) {
    if(!current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'ethaddyadd', $_POST["ethaddyadd"]);
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields_uny' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields_uny' );

function extra_user_profile_fields_uny( $user ) { 
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <td>Ethaddyadd</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ethaddyadd">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input').addClass('regular-text');
        $('input[name=ethaddyadd]').val('<?php echo get_the_author_meta('ethaddyadd', $user->ID); ?>');
    </script>
<?php 
}

function new_modify_user_table_uny( $column ) {
    $column['ethaddyadd'] = 'Ethaddyadd';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table_uny' );

function new_modify_user_table_row_uny( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id);
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'ethaddyadd' :
            $ethaddyadd = $meta['ethaddyadd'][0];
            return $ethaddyadd;
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row_uny', 10, 3 );
```

[image: Code working but empty value now screenshot]

I also have a code that shows the data from the mysql column that I need if I set a root test.php file and test it.

```
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php');

$get = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT 
                    addresses.name
            FROM 
                ".$wpdb->prefix."addresses as addresses
                
                ");
                
/*
echo "<pre>";print_r($get);echo "</pre>";
*/

foreach ( $get as $print )   { ?>
 
                  <pre>  <?php echo $print->name; ?> </pre>

            <?php 
            

            }

?>
```

[image: Code Output from file in the WP root folder just for testing code]

**¿ How can I then tell the database/wordpress input the other table value into the user's usermeta custom value ?**

Final screenshot.
[image: Desired result after all the process]

Thank you for all your knowledge sharing ;)